# Can't dismiss flags from question page

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools

Manually dismissing a flag from a question page appears to be broken; nothing happens when I click the "no action needed" button. Tried on Chromium 32.0.1700.19 and Firefox 25.0, on Linux. Dismissing from the flag list still works fine.

Comment: Broken on windows 7 + Chrome too

Comment: Pretty sure I just did this last night.. Though I suppose it could have broken since then.

Comment: @Seth I imagine it's recent, you can't break dismissing flags without somebody noticing pretty fast

Comment: Can I get a diamond so I can reproduce? :D

Comment: Yeah, probably my bug - looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added individual flag dismissing and there was an issue on the Question/Show page - it should now be resolved.

Going to be honest, there are some UI issues still, e.g. after clearing a single flag, the UI might disappear from Question/Show.  Trying to sort it out, but the code isn't very extensible.